# In 'gain practice', what's the meaning of 'practice'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And our work of figuring out a text’s implications tests our analytical powers. In considering what a text suggests, we gain practice in making sense of texts. (You Are What You Read: A Practical Guide to Reading Well / Robert DiYanni · 2022)

What's the meaning of 'practice'?

Comment: Do you have a dictionary?  If so, why isn't it helping?

Comment: there are lots of meanings

Comment: "Practice makes perfect" (i.e. doing it repeatedly until you get better at it) is fairly obviously the meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

In "gain practice", "practice" is used as a synonym for "experience" or "skill". It's a little hard to understand, because "practice" is what you do to "gain experience" or improve skills. I think it would be better written without "gain": "In considering what a text suggests, we practice making sense of texts."